# How do you copy a folder tree with invalid characters and too long paths from a network drive?

Tags: windows, file-transfer, robocopy

I've tried `robocopy /E /256 z:\source c:\target` but that doesn't rename files with invalid characters.

I tried dragging the folder to my desktop and 7zipping it but it also fails on invalid characters.

What to do?

--

Update:

- git-bash for windows can't see paths with : either
- Ubuntu subsystem for Windows doesn't map network drives to /mnt to access them

Still haven't tried a live Linux USB drive yet

Comment: What are the invalid characters that each is choking on? Can you perhaps rename the files at the source using CMD or PowerShell?

Comment: I think it's a colon and question mark. No, I can't rename the source.

Comment: You will _never_ be able to do anything with those files in Windows; they're both blatantly illegal characters for Windows filenames. The implication is that these are files on a network drive, and the host computer for them is running an OS where those are _not_ illegal characters. You will have to have the administrator rename those files to not contain the illegal characters. If the source is _not_ a network drive, or the remote _is_ running Windows, the filesystem in question is corrupt, and you cannot rely on the data's validity.

Comment: @Jeff: Although Z: is likely to be a network drive, characters like question marks are perfectly legal in the NTFS filesystem and in the Windows kernel (so it's allowed to use them via Interix, WSL, and _possibly_ even SMB shares with the right protocol extensions). They're just not legal in "normal" Win32 apps, but aren't in themselves a sign of FS corruption.

Comment: @grawity - Read my comment again - what I said was that _if_ the _network host_ is running Windows, the filesystem is corrupt (as, being Windows, it wouldn't allow those characters), _or_ if the source drive is _not_ a network drive (hence local, on the Windows workstation), the filesystem is corrupt, as, being Windows, it wouldn't allow those characters. If both of those conditions are _not_ true - that is, the drive is a network drive _and_ the network server does _not_ run Windows - then the administrator will have to deal with renaming the files to eliminate the illegal chars.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: Win32 doesn't allow these characters _but NTFS does,_ therefore having such files on NTFS (if they happen to come from another OS) is not an indication of FS corruption of any kind.

Comment: @grawity - If they came from another OS, they _still can't end up on a **Windows** filesystem; Windows wouldn't allow it._ Read both of my previous comments; I do recognize the difference between "NTFS" and "server runs Windows".

Comment: @grawity - In any case, because of the way NTFS alternate data streams are implemented, the colon _is_ an illegal filename character for NTFS, regardless of the server OS.

Comment: @grawity - and the question mark is illegal in Linux, so WSL isn't an answer, either.

Comment: @grawity - We also don't even know what filesystem the purported network drive is using.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access individual files using the [`dir /x` command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir), which shows the 8.3 character filename, this *might* enable you to copy them using that name.

It is also possible that [the character that looks like a colon is another.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386344/how-to-get-a-file-in-windows-with-a-colon-in-the-filename) Hwever, in that case, there may be other illegal characters.

Another possibility is to run Linux from a [Live USB drive with persistence](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) to access the files, copy them to the USB's ext*n* partition, rename them and copy to the HDD.

Comment: Thanks. `dir /x` still shows the colon in the folder name though. I can navigate into it but not copy files onto my local host. I'll try the Linux idea. Maybe the Ubuntu subsystem for Windows can do it.

Comment: You may still need an ext3 or ext4 partition (perhaps on USB) to copy the files.